# How does one create a component which can effect things outside of runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I want to make a custom component. One of the functions I want to have is the ability to create and modify set of points that make up a circle. For example, specify point count:10, and on field update, a circle made up of 10 triangles is drawn in the editor.

Then I want to be able to drag the vertices of the created circle. I feel like I might be able to do this during runtime, but I'm curious how to do it out of runtime. For example, the built in "Box Collider" component has a button that allows you to edit the collider size in the editor.

I looked around and can't find a resource - I feel like there has to be a place for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute scripts like if you were in runtime using the [ExecuteInEditMode] annotation at the begining of your class.

Check out the [documentation here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html)

For the functionality you want, you have [Handles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.html), to manipulate objects properties.

Also you'll want to develop visual aids for your tool, so you can accomplish this using [Gizmos](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.html).

Answer (score 0):

Google "Custom Editors for Unity" - there's a whole section of the docs for this. You have a wide array of options, from the simple to the powerful.

I recommend catlikecoding's tutorials, that are clearly than the official docs, and take you through the process step by step.

One of them almost exactly describes your situation:

http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/editor/star/